# WiFi 6 2x2 vs WiFi 5 4x4

Tags: networking, wifi

I am in the process of an infrastructure build out and I’ve narrowed down my AP selections between two. One being a 802.11ac 4x4 MIMO and the other being a WiFi 6 (802.11ax) 2x2 MIMO.

Does anyone have any technical comments they could provide on the real world advantages or disadvantages between the two? Ideally it would be an easy decision if the vendor I have chosen had a WiFi 6 4x4, but unfortunately they don’t.

On average, each AP will have less then 20 clients with general purpose traffic and some video streaming.

Comment: Any chance you are looking at the Aruba Instant-on APs? That's what I am, and debating between the AP15 and AP22.

Comment: @aggieNick02 No. This Ubiquity UniFi gear. But the brand should not matter and I’m still curious as to what the best route would be.

Comment: Gotcha. Was just curious. I guess multiple companies have the new fancy wifi 6 but not in the 4x4 configurations yet. For Aruba, it makes the wifi 6 option cheaper than the most powerful 5 ac.

Comment: @aggieNick02 Yea. My thoughts are go with the 4x4 until more WiFi 6 options come out. Unless someone answers here and changes my mind

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the way to go too.

Answer (score 5):

Mimo Wifi speed is a factor of the single-channel speed ("1x1" aka SISO) multiplied by the antenna mimo configuration shared by the transmitter and receiver. Wifi generations tends to determine the 1x1 speed, available equipment tends to determine the mimo configuration (1x1, 2x2, 4x4, ...).

In the context of a single AP and a single client, the configuration "4x4" means that each side of the connection has 4 antennas, for 8 antennas total. 4x4 mimo can achieve a 4x speed-up over the base channel speed. If 1x1 speed were 100 mbit/sec, the 4x4 mimo could achieve 400 mbit/sec in the same channel conditions.

From there, things are fairly "algebraic". If you have a single AP and a single client running in a 2x2 configuration, you'll get half the performance as if the client and AP were running in a 4x4 config, but double 1x1.

If you have a single AP with 4 antennas, and a single client with 2 antennas, aka 4x2, then the system can only generate a 2x multiplier on the stream bitrate and so generally the system performs the same as a 2x2 config. However, the extra transmit antennas afford the AP the opportunity to overcome noise/fading by using diversity antenna techniques. As a result, the bitrate-to-snr curve for 4x2 tends to be better than 2x2.

Things remain generally "algebraic" when introducing multiple clients (relevant to your situation). If you have a base station with 4 antennas, and 4 clients each with one antenna, then you have four 4x1 configurations, which will have an aggregate capacity similar to what you'd get if you had one client in 4x4 configuration. So if a 4x4 client can get 400 mbit/sec, then four 4x1 clients can get each 100 mbit/sec. This is technically known as Multi-user Mimo ("MU-MIMO") and wifi5 only supports MU-MIMO from the AP to the client ("downlink") while wifi6 supports it in both directions.

...

To get more at the heart of your question:

Wifi5's fastest official MCS is MCS9 which can do 866 mbit/sec in 1x1, 1733 in 2x2, 2600 in 3x3, and 3466 in 4x4.

Wifi6's fastest official MCS is MCS11 which can do 1201 mbit/sec in 1x1, 2402 in 2x2, 3603 in 3x3, and 4804 in 4x4.

That's all assuming that you have the SNR to support it, keeping in mind the Shannon–Hartley theorem: the capacity of a 1x1 channel has a maximum theoretical capacity C = SNR * bandwidth; you're not doing any better than that.

...

So if we go by the numbers, then wifi6 2x2 = 2402, while wifi5 4x4 = 3466, so wifi5 wins.

But there's a billion complications that matter for a practical deployment - wifi6 has a whole bunch more tricks up its sleeve for making the best it can of sub-optimal conditions that might be present in your network. And it supports a larger frequency range which may mean better opportunities for cleaner air.

Comment: WOW - what a detailed and enlightning answer!